# If statement for regex in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check matches given string to the pattern.

Input may look like this: `3256-10wyput`
So we've used this pattern `[0-9]{4}\-[0-9a-z]{7}`

I want to prepare an if statement which checks does input suit to my regex.

Pseudo code looks like that:

```
if regex in string:
    return True
```

How it should look like?
Thanks for advices.
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a check with the [re.match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) function:

```
import re

if re.match('[0-9]{4}-[0-9a-z]{7}', '3256-10wyput'):
    return True
```

Comment: Ok. I was not enough specific. String is generated randomly, but such regex validates it. How universal if statement should look like?